# Difference between PACKETS and FRAMES

Tags: networking, network-programming

Two words commonly used in networking world - Packets and frames.

Can anyone please give the detail difference between these two words?

Hope it might sounds silly but does it mean as below

A packet is the PDU(Protocol Data Unit) at layer 3 (network layer - ip packet) of the networking OSI model.

A frame is the PDU of layer 2 (data link) of the OSI model.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

*Packets* and *Frames* are the names given to [Protocol data units (PDUs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit) at different [network layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

- **Segments**/**Datagrams** are units of data in the *Transport Layer*.

  In the case of the internet, the term **Segment** typically refers to TCP, while **Datagram** typically refers to UDP. However **Datagram** can also be used in a more general sense and refer to other layers ([link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1594)):

  > Datagram
  >
  > A self-contained, independent entity of data carrying sufficient information to be routed from the source to the destination computer without reliance on earlier exchanges between this source and destination computer andthe transporting network.
- **Packets** are units of data in the *Network Layer* (IP in case of the Internet)
- **Frames** are units of data in the *Link Layer* (e.g. Wifi,
  Bluetooth, Ethernet, etc).

[image]

Comment: This kind of implies that the entire datagram must fit in a single frame.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *(I know this is three years later, but I just saw this).* A datagram is simply a construct of a protocol header, and included bits. A **Frame** is a datagram at L2. A **Packet** is a datagram at L3. Packets get carried within a Frame, so the Packet datagram *does indeed* fit inside a Frame datagram. [More details on this answer at Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/50098/3675).

Comment: If you are running UDP over ATM, the UDP datagram is divided over many ATM frames. The same datagram can be sent more than once in different frames, a frame only exists on a single link.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Right. I think we're on the same page.  This: `[UDP][110010100011]` is a Segment, a datagram at L4. And each of these are Frames: `[ATM][UDP1100]` `[ATM][1010]` `[ATM][0011]` -- datagrams at L2. *Inside* the first frame is *the first third* of the UDP Segment. *Inside* the second frame is *the second third* of the UDP segment (etc). All four instances above are datagrams -- one Segment, and three Frames.

Comment: Segments are units of TCP, which segments a data stream. UDP uses datagrams, which is actually part of the name (User _Datagram_ Protocol). UDP does not segment the data as it is a message-based protocol vs. TCP, which is a stream-based protocol.

Comment: @RonMaupin Valid point, thanks. Although the term "Datagram" is more general, and doesn't refer to a specific network layer. According to RFC 1594 a datagram is *A self-contained, independent entity of data carrying sufficient information to be routed from the source to the destination computer*.

Comment: "_doesn't refer to a specific network layer._" That is why UDP name is _User Datagram_ Protocol, telling you what network layer. It provides a protocol for the user process to use. RFC 792 explains: "_This User Datagram  Protocol  (UDP)  is  defined  to  make  available  a datagram   mode  of  packet-switched   computer communication  in  the environment  of  an  interconnected  set  of  computer  networks._"

Answer (score 35):

Actually, there are five words commonly used when we talk about layers of reference models (or protocol stacks): `data`, `segment`, `packet`, `frame` and `bit`. And the term PDU (`Protocol Data Unit`) is a generic term used to refer to the packets in different layers of the OSI model. Thus PDU gives an abstract idea of the data packets. The PDU has a different meaning in different layers still we can use it as a common term.

When we come to your question, we can call all of them by using the general term `PDU`, but if you want to call them specifically at a given layer:

- **Data:** PDU of Application, Presentation and Session Layers
- **Segment:** PDU of Transport Layer
- **Packet:** PDU of network Layer
- **Frame:** PDU of data-link Layer
- **Bit:** PDU of physical Layer

Here is a diagram, since a picture is worth a thousand words:
[image: a picture is worth a thousand words]

Comment: So the Frames contain all of the units of data inside the Network, Transport, and Application layer?

Answer (score 33):

A packet is a general term for a formatted unit of data carried by a network. It is not necessarily connected to a specific OSI model layer.

For example, in the Ethernet protocol on the physical layer (layer 1), the unit of data is called an "Ethernet packet", which has an [Ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame)  (layer 2) as its payload. But the unit of data of the Network layer (layer 3) is also called a "packet".

A frame is also a unit of data transmission. In computer networking the term is only used in the context of the Data link layer (layer 2).

Another semantical difference between packet and frame is that a frame envelops your payload with a header and a trailer, just like a painting in a frame, while a packet usually only has a header.

But in the end they mean roughly the same thing and the distinction is used to avoid confusion and repetition when talking about the different layers.

Comment: The “Painting frame” analogy has built my intuitive understanding of the term “Frame”. Thanks!

Comment: is there any RFC which has refered to "Ethernet packet" and "Ethernet frame"?

Answer (score 9):

Consider TCP over ATM. ATM uses 48 byte frames, but clearly TCP packets can be bigger than that. A frame is the chunk of data sent as a unit over the data link (Ethernet, ATM). A packet is the chunk of data sent as a unit over the layer above it (IP). If the data link is made specifically for IP, as Ethernet and WiFi are, these will be the same size and packets will correspond to frames.

Comment: Do you mean that considering length

Packet length means L4 or above layers and frame length means whole packet with Ethernet, ip and above layers.

Comment: No. There is no rule that requires the entire packet to fit in a single frame. (Except in specific protocols like Ethernet. But this is not the case for ATM where a single packet may be split over multiple frames.)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense...

Answer (score 5):

Packet

A packet is the unit of data that is routed between an origin and a destination on the Internet or any other packet-switched network. When any file (e-mail message, HTML file, Graphics Interchange Format file, Uniform Resource Locator request, and so forth) is sent from one place to another on the Internet, the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) layer of TCP/IP divides the file into "chunks" of an efficient size for routing. Each of these packets is separately numbered and includes the Internet address of the destination. The individual packets for a given file may travel different routes through the Internet. When they have all arrived, they are reassembled into the original file (by the TCP layer at the receiving end).

Frame

1) In telecommunications, a frame is data that is transmitted between network points as a unit complete with addressing and necessary protocol control information. A frame is usually transmitted serial bit by bit and contains a header field and a trailer field that "frame" the data. (Some control frames contain no data.)

2) In time-division multiplexing (TDM), a frame is a complete cycle of events within the time division period.

3) In film and video recording and playback, a frame is a single image in a sequence of images that are recorded and played back.

4) In computer video display technology, a frame is the image that is sent to the display image rendering devices. It is continuously updated or refreshed from a frame buffer, a highly accessible part of video RAM.

5) In artificial intelligence (AI) applications, a frame is a set of data with information about a particular object, process, or image. An example is the iris-print visual recognition system used to identify users of certain bank automated teller machines. This system compares the frame of data for a potential user with the frames in its database of authorized users.