# How Wireshark notice which TCP packets belong to the same HTTP response?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

By which fields of TCP packet, we can tell if it is a continuation of a previous TCP packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be part of the same TCP stream, TCP [segments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464376/3199595) must belong to the same session .i.e have the same source IP, source port, destination IP and destination port.

Once two segments are from the same stream, they can be ordered by the sequence number field in the TCP header. The sequence number of the next segment should be equal to the sequence number of the **previous** segment plus the number of bytes in the **previous** segment.

So if we have a segment with seq# 1000 and a payload of 200 bytes, the next one should have the number 1200.

Answer (score 0):

[TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol?oldformat=true#TCP_segment_structure): Sequence number, Acknowledgement number.
In Wireshark, you can Right Click on a packet and choose Follow to follow TCP or HTTP stream. It should help seeing how there values change from packet to packet.